# python django models request.user

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I am trying to implement a model that automatically filters data based on the user. I was able to modify the user model and add a value for "company" that references a table of companies.

I have a table that has a company value as well (call it data_table). Ideally when ANY user logs into the system, the data filtered to match company value on user to company value on data_table.

So far I have it working, but I want to overwrite the get_query method to incorporate what I have and I can't figure out how to get the current logged in user into the model without passing it from the view.

I would think that in the below I could just use in models.py:

```
current_user = request.user
cid =  current_user.company.id
```

The advantage being I don't have to remember to put the filter in when I use the model.

The error that gets thrown is:

**Exception Value:

global name 'request' is not defined**

Here is what works:

**models.py:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

class data_tableManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, cid):
        return super(data_tableManager, self).get_queryset().filter(company_filter_id=cid)

class data_table(models.Model):
    company_filter = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    data_column = models.CharField(db_column='dc', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.Manager() # would like to replace this with data_tableManager
    company_objects = data_tableManager() # The company specific manager.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import data_table

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def data_view(request):
    current_user = request.user
    cid =  current_user.company.id
    print current_user.get_company()

    return render(
        request,
        'example.html',
        {
            'filtered1': data_table.objects.filter(company_filter_id=cid),
            'filtered2': data_table.company_objects.get_queryset(cid),
            'cid':cid,
        }
    )
```